# Copied unique values from sorted array to new array***

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, unique

I am working on a Java problem for my Data Structures class.

Essentially, we are supposed to take a sorted array, remove any duplicates from it, and then copy these unique values into a new array. However, the challenging bit is that we are only allowed to iterate through the array once. Every solution I have come across requires iterating through the array at least twice: once for the "removal" of duplicate values, and another time to copy the unique values to a new array.

Is there any way that I can copy the unique values to a new array while I am in the process of identifying the unique ones? I am banging my head on a wall and coming across all sorts of OutOfBounds exceptions, trying to figure this one out.

I should also mention that the size of the array is considered a given.

Thanks for reading!

Here is my code so far for the creation of the new array:

```
public static double[] removeDuplicates (double[] list) {

        int numOfUniques = numUnique(list);
        if (numOfUniques == 0){
            return null;
        }
        else if (list.length < 2){
            return list;
        }

        int counter = 0;
        double[] uniquesArray = new double[numOfUniques];
        uniquesArray[0] = list[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++){
            if (list[i] == list[counter]){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                counter++;
                uniquesArray[counter] = list[i];
            }   
        }

      return uniquesArray;
}
```

And for an array with values { 10, 11, 12 }, this has been returning an array with values { 10, 11, 0 }

Comment: What's the type of the array?

Comment: It's a double type array.

Comment: You can do it in one pass, but the final array size is not known until after the complete pass (obviously), and in java arrays have a fixed size. This means that while you could do the dedupe-and-copy in one pass, the final array must be *copied* to an array of the correct size *after* the deduping. The copy process requires a full pass, albeit of the final values. Is that allowed? If not, is returning a List acceptable?

Comment: That makes sense. This function is actually linked to a function that determines the number of unique elements in the same array, so I should be able to create an array of the correct size before-hand. I'm just having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to set the unique values to the correct index of the new array. So far I've been getting lots of "almosts", with the last or first index of the new array tending to be 0, for some reason.

Comment: If you have sorted array like `[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5]` you need to add first element to new array and remember last value that you added to your new array. If the value that you remembered is the same as the next value in the sorted array you skip it. Oldarray[0] = 1, newaaray[0] = 1, remember = 1; oldarray[1] = 1, oldarray == remember -> skip it. I hope you can understand what I am saying.

Comment: Show your code so far (even if it doesn't work) by editing your question to include it, and I'll show you mine.

Comment: Okay, edited to include my code. Hope it doesn't make you shake your head too much.

Answer (score 1):

Add (during iteration through the `List`) the values to a `Set` and afterwards create a `List` from this `Set`. A `Set` accepts only unique values - duplicates are always discarded.

Comment: Although this is an O(n) solution, this approach uses O(n) space, but there's an O(1) space solution (not counting the output array, which is unavoidable)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a data-structure class I would assume that you have to it only using arrays, try out this one :

```
public double[] getUniqueItems (double[] array){
        double[] unique = new double[array.length];
        Arrays.sort(array);

        double currentItem = array[0];
        unique[0] = currentItem;

        for(int i = 1; i<array.length;i++){
            if(array[i] != currentItem){
                unique[i] = array[i];
                currentItem = array[i];
            }
        }

        return unique;
    }
```

Comment: The array is already sorted. Also, the output may contain duplicates (I'll leave it to you to figure out why)

Comment: Unfortunately, this one doesn't seem to be working well. If I pass in an array of {1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, it passes back an array of {1, 2, 3, 4, 0}.

Comment: for(int i= 1,j = 1; i <array.length;i++){
            if(array[i] != currentItem){
                unique[j] = array[i];
                currentItem = array[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

this code to ensure not having gaps, regarding the 0, it is the initial value for the double, if you declare any double array, all items will have initial value of 0.0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would be allowed for your assignment, but you can do what you want with a Java 8 oneliner (no loops at all):

```
    double[] dA = ..... // your input array
    Arrays.sort(dA);    // sort it
    double[] dB = IntStream.range(0, dA.length)
                    .mapToDouble(i -> dA[i]).distinct().toArray();
```

---

EDIT: As noted by Bohemian this can be shortened to:

```
    double[] dB = DoubleStream.of(dA).distinct().toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Robin. Unfortunately, we're not allowed to call any other functions. It's a real head-scratcher! I'll keep your solution in mind for the future, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the great responses, gals and guys! I took a lot of what each of you said into consideration and I believe I've got the problem worked out. Here is my solution(numUnique is a function that returns the number of unique items in a sorted array):

public static double[] removeDuplicates (double[] list) {

```
    int numOfUniques = numUnique(list);
    if (numOfUniques == 0){
        return null;
    }
    else if (list.length < 2){
        return list;
    }


    double[] unique = new double[numOfUniques];
    double currentItem = list[0];
    unique[0] = currentItem;
    int j = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
        if (currentItem != list[i]){
            unique[j] = list[i];
            currentItem = list[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return unique;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JDK provides a simple (albeit O(n) space complexity) solution that uses only one pass:

```
return DoubleStream.of(input).distinct().toArray();
```

---

If you are required to roll your own implementation, consider that because the input is sorted, you only need to keep elements that are *different* to the previous element (plus the first element).

One implementation could be:

```
double[] input; // given this
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && input[i] != input[i-1])
        count++;
    input[count] = input[i];
}
return Arrays.copyOf(input, count);
```

This uses an in-place building of the result array, thus using only O(1) space.